# Seems like a bug in Azure SQL Server Data Warehouse?

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, data-warehouse

Below is the script I am running on Microsoft Azure SQL Data Warehouse - 10.0.8529.1.  I tried it on local SQL Server 2014, everything worked as expected.

```
select @@version

-- Returns 1 rows, as expected
select
    cast(null as varchar(8000)) as col1
where 
    1=0
union all
select top 1
    'TEST'
from
    bl

-- Returns 60 rows (WHY?????)
select
    cast(null as varchar(max)) as col1
where 
    1=0
union all
select top 1
    'TEST'
from
    bl
```

The following is the result:

```
----------------
Microsoft Azure SQL Data Warehouse - 10.0.8529.1 Jan 16 2017 09:40:27 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation

col1
----------------
TEST

1 row

col1
----------------
TEST
TEST
.
.
.
.
.
.TEST

60 rows
```

Explain plan for the 1st query is as following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<dsql_query
    number_nodes="4"
    number_distributions="60"
    number_distributions_per_node="15">
    <sql>select
    cast(null as varchar(8000)) as col1
where 
    1=0
union all
select top 1
    'TEST'
from
    bl</sql>
    <dsql_operations
        total_cost="0"
        total_number_operations="1">
        <dsql_operation
            operation_type="RETURN">
            <location
                distribution="AllDistributions" />
            <select>SELECT [T1_1].[col] AS [col]
FROM   (SELECT TOP (CAST ((1) AS BIGINT)) CAST (N'TEST' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS AS VARCHAR (4)) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS AS [col]
        FROM   [dev-pmoldw].[STARNET].[BL] AS T2_1) AS T1_1</select>
        </dsql_operation>
    </dsql_operations>
</dsql_query>
```

Explain plan for varchar(max) query is as following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<dsql_query
    number_nodes="4"
    number_distributions="60"
    number_distributions_per_node="15">
    <sql>select
    cast(null as varchar(max)) as col1
where 
    1=0
union all
select top 1
    'TEST'
from
    bl</sql>
    <dsql_operations
        total_cost="0"
        total_number_operations="1">
        <dsql_operation
            operation_type="RETURN">
            <location
                distribution="AllDistributions" />
            <select>SELECT [T1_1].[col] AS [col]
FROM   (SELECT TOP (CAST ((1) AS BIGINT)) CONVERT (VARCHAR (MAX), CAST (N'TEST' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS AS VARCHAR (4)) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS, 0) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS AS [col]
        FROM   [dev-pmoldw].[STARNET].[BL] AS T2_1) AS T1_1</select>
        </dsql_operation>
    </dsql_operations>
</dsql_query>
```

(Edit: Reported here https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback/Details/3120055)

Comment: What does the actual execution plan XML look like for the second case? Can you upload it somewhere?

Comment: Sorry Martin, Azure Sql DWH does not support SET SHOWPLAN_TEXT or SET SHOWPLAN_ALL.

Comment: Looks like you need to use EXPLAIN. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt631615.aspx though that is a different format I'm not familiar with, Maybe it will shed some light though.

Comment: Thanks!  Learned something today about Explain Plan on Azure.

Comment: So you're getting the same number of rows as `number_distributions`

Comment: I agree with the reason why I am getting 60 rows.  But why am I getting 60 rows instead of 1,  Right?

Comment: Presumably a bug. How does the varchar 8000 plan differ?

Comment: There are some subtle differences in the plan, but nothing sticks out.

Comment: How many rows do you have in the bl table? Isn't it around 6000? (just a wild guess)

Comment: Close to 9 million rows are in the bl table.

Comment: Probably best reporting it here https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback